# JS works in jsfiddle, but wont work in Magento checkout

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

I have added JS to my checkout with `jsrequire` and I can see my JS file in the developer console.

For testing I tried to `console.log` the firstname field value on input, like this:

```
   var name = $("[name='firstname']");


   name.on('input', function(){ console.log(name[0].value);})
```

It is working in JSfiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v127c14p/75/).

But it won't work in Magento checkout, I don't get any errors (I do get errors if I write incorrect JS/JQ code).

Comment: Did you check the loading of the input elements and js, normally magento 2 uses knockout js to load checkout fields so its load after page load, so please try to use data binding or render events.if you cant find you can use waiting for content load like js fixes .

Comment: @Lasantha I was under the impression that if I use `on input` it will for sure be called when the fields are already loaded...

Comment: Try like this  $(document).on('EVENT','SELECTOR',function(){
      // your code
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it seems like Magento doesn't like `var name = $("[name='firstname']");` selector.

I changed it to: `var name = document.getElementsByName("firstname");`

And it works.

**EDIT** Turns out I needed something called `delegation`, because the fields are generated later and `.on` won't be applied.

This is the way to do it

`$(document).on('click',"input[name='street[0]']",function(){}`

(`document` can be changed for "closer" non changing parent element)